# Determine country from Google Scholar Profile

Tags: python, location, country, tld, google-scholar

I am currently working on a project scraping data from Google Scholar. I wish to scrape the country of residence of each profile, however this is not clearly listed. For example, from [this page](https://scholar.google.pl/citations?user=Wm3BMoQAAAAJ&hl=en) I would want UK, given that the email address listed is from ucl.ac.uk. To give another example, from [this page](https://scholar.google.pl/citations?user=ey8OGEYAAAAJ&hl=en) I would want to give the Netherlands given the email address is from vumc.nl. However, if we were to look at [this profile](https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=VGoSakQAAAAJ) from the URL TLD, we cannot determine the country.

So far I have written this code to capture the domain:

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import string
import time


url = 'https://scholar.google.com/citations?user=VGoSakQAAAAJ'

page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
buttons = soup.findAll("div", { "id" : "gsc_prf_ivh" })
for each in buttons:
    s = each.text
```

So, how can I determine from a user's Google Scholar profile, with fairly high accuracy, their country?

Comment: I hate to be the one to say it but you seem to have omitted your question.

Comment: @BillBell Have clarified!